# No such file or directory - От чего может выдаваться сообщение при старте приложения?

Tags: linux

Простенькое приложение на libuv. Теперь собирается в alpine, но не стартует. Права есть, линовка в порядке.

```
-rwxr-xr-x    1 root     root         14808 Nov 23 16:19 /usr/local/bin/collector
```

Трассировка

```
# strace /usr/local/bin/collector
execve("/usr/local/bin/collector", ["/usr/local/bin/collector"], 0x7ffcab666640 /* 34 vars */) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
```

Файл

```
/usr/local/bin/collector: ELF 64-bit LSB shared object, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV),
dynamically linked, interpreter /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2, for GNU/Linux 3.2.0,
BuildID[sha1]=d174d4d1db763b1b5106a796e85cdd3c0460e975, stripped
```

Хед

```
# head -n 2 /usr/local/bin/collector | hexdump -C
00000000  7f 45 4c 46 02 01 01 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |.ELF............|
00000010  03 00 3e 00 01 00 00 00  30 0f 00 00 00 00 00 00  |..>.....0.......|
00000020  40 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  18 33 00 00 00 00 00 00  |@........3......|
00000030  00 00 00 00 40 00 38 00  09 00 40 00 1b 00 1a 00  |....@.8...@.....|
00000040  06 00 00 00 05 00 00 00  40 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |........@.......|
00000050  40 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  40 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |@.......@.......|
00000060  f8 01 00 00 00 00 00 00  f8 01 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
00000070  08 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  03 00 00 00 04 00 00 00  |................|
00000080  38 02 00 00 00 00 00 00  38 02 00 00 00 00 00 00  |8.......8.......|
00000090  38 02 00 00 00 00 00 00  1c 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |8...............|
000000a0  1c 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  01 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
000000b0  01 00 00 00 05 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
000000c0  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
000000d0  00 22 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 22 00 00 00 00 00 00  |."......."......|
000000e0  00 00 20 00 00 00 00 00  01 00 00 00 06 00 00 00  |.. .............|
000000f0  80 2d 00 00 00 00 00 00  80 2d 20 00 00 00 00 00  |.-.......- .....|
00000100  80 2d 20 00 00 00 00 00  8e 04 00 00 00 00 00 00  |.- .............|
00000110  c8 04 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 20 00 00 00 00 00  |.......... .....|
00000120  02 00 00 00 06 00 00 00  90 2d 00 00 00 00 00 00  |.........-......|
00000130  90 2d 20 00 00 00 00 00  90 2d 20 00 00 00 00 00  |.- ......- .....|
00000140  40 02 00 00 00 00 00 00  40 02 00 00 00 00 00 00  |@.......@.......|
00000150  08 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  04 00 00 00 04 00 00 00  |................|
00000160  54 02 00 00 00 00 00 00  54 02 00 00 00 00 00 00  |T.......T.......|
00000170  54 02 00 00 00 00 00 00  44 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |T.......D.......|
00000180  44 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  04 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |D...............|
00000190  50 e5 74 64 04 00 00 00  98 1f 00 00 00 00 00 00  |P.td............|
000001a0  98 1f 00 00 00 00 00 00  98 1f 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
000001b0  74 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  74 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |t.......t.......|
000001c0  04 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  51 e5 74 64 06 00 00 00  |........Q.td....|
000001d0  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
*
000001f0  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  10 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
00000200  52 e5 74 64 04 00 00 00  80 2d 00 00 00 00 00 00  |R.td.....-......|
00000210  80 2d 20 00 00 00 00 00  80 2d 20 00 00 00 00 00  |.- ......- .....|
00000220  80 02 00 00 00 00 00 00  80 02 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
00000230  01 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  2f 6c 69 62 36 34 2f 6c  |......../lib64/l|
00000240  64 2d 6c 69 6e 75 78 2d  78 38 36 2d 36 34 2e 73  |d-linux-x86-64.s|
00000250  6f 2e 32 00 04 00 00 00  10 00 00 00 01 00 00 00  |o.2.............|
00000260  47 4e 55 00 00 00 00 00  03 00 00 00 02 00 00 00  |GNU.............|
00000270  00 00 00 00 04 00 00 00  14 00 00 00 03 00 00 00  |................|
00000280  47 4e 55 00 d1 74 d4 d1  db 76 3b 1b 51 06 a7 96  |GNU..t...v;.Q...|
00000290  e8 5c dd 3c 04 60 e9 75  03 00 00 00 24 00 00 00  |.\.<.`.u....$...|
000002a0  01 00 00 00 06 00 00 00  88 c1 20 01 00 04 40 0b  |.......... ...@.|
000002b0  24 00 00 00 26 00 00 00  29 00 00 00 42 45 d5 ec  |$...&...)...BE..|
000002c0  bb e3 92 7c b8 8d f1 0e  38 f2 8b 1c d9 71 58 1c  |...|....8....qX.|
000002d0  eb d3 ef 0e 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
000002e0  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
000002f0  78 00 00 00 12 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |x...............|
00000300  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  aa 01 00 00 12 00 00 00  |................|
00000310  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
00000320  f6 00 00 00 12 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
00000330  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  6a 00 00 00 12 00 00 00  |........j.......|
00000340  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
00000350  ea 00 00 00 12 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
00000360  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  d7 00 00 00 12 00 00 00  |................|
00000370  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
00000380  b7 01 00 00 22 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |...."...........|
00000390  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  51 00 00 00 12 00 00 00  |........Q.......|
000003a0  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
000003b0  a3 00 00 00 12 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
000003c0  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  8d 01 00 00 12 00 00 00  |................|
000003d0  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
000003e0  b1 01 00 00 12 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
000003f0  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  71 01 00 00 12 00 00 00  |........q.......|
00000400  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
00000410  94 00 00 00 12 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
00000420  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  0e 01 00 00 12 00 00 00  |................|
00000430  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
00000440  ad 00 00 00 12 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
00000450  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  de 00 00 00 12 00 00 00  |................|
00000460  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
00000470  7c 01 00 00 12 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  ||...............|
00000480  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  e4 01 00 00 12 00 00 00  |................|
00000490  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
000004a0  20 01 00 00 12 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  | ...............|
000004b0  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  6c 01 00 00 12 00 00 00  |........l.......|
000004c0  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
000004d0  58 00 00 00 12 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |X...............|
000004e0  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  d8 01 00 00 12 00 00 00  |................|
000004f0  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
00000500  87 00 00 00 12 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
00000510  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  94 01 00 00 12 00 00 00  |................|
00000520  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
00000530  a9 01 00 00 12 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
00000540  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  77 01 00 00 12 00 00 00  |........w.......|
00000550  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
00000560  c5 00 00 00 12 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
00000570  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  61 00 00 00 12 00 00 00  |........a.......|
00000580  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
00000590  1b 00 00 00 20 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |.... ...........|
000005a0  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  de 01 00 00 12 00 00 00  |................|
000005b0  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
000005c0  02 01 00 00 12 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
000005d0  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  c6 01 00 00 12 00 00 00  |................|
000005e0  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
000005f0  0c 00 00 00 20 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |.... ...........|
00000600  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  37 00 00 00 20 00 00 00  |........7... ...|
00000610  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
00000620  a2 01 00 00 12 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
00000630  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  e9 01 00 00 10 00 17 00  |................|
00000640  0e 32 20 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |.2 .............|
00000650  fc 01 00 00 10 00 18 00  48 32 20 00 00 00 00 00  |........H2 .....|
00000660  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  08 01 00 00 12 00 0b 00  |................|
00000670  28 0d 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |(...............|
00000680  9b 01 00 00 11 00 18 00  20 32 20 00 00 00 00 00  |........ 2 .....|
00000690  08 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  f0 01 00 00 10 00 18 00  |................|
000006a0  0e 32 20 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |.2 .............|
000006b0  1a 01 00 00 12 00 0e 00  74 1e 00 00 00 00 00 00  |........t.......|
000006c0  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 6c 69 62 70 71 2e 73  |.........libpq.s|
000006d0  6f 2e 35 00 5f 5f 67 6d  6f 6e 5f 73 74 61 72 74  |o.5.__gmon_start|
000006e0  5f 5f 00 5f 49 54 4d 5f  64 65 72 65 67 69 73 74  |__._ITM_deregist|
000006f0  65 72 54 4d 43 6c 6f 6e  65 54 61 62 6c 65 00 5f  |erTMCloneTable._|
00000700  49 54 4d 5f 72 65 67 69  73 74 65 72 54 4d 43 6c  |ITM_registerTMCl|
00000710  6f 6e 65 54 61 62 6c 65  00 50 51 65 78 65 63 00  |oneTable.PQexec.|
00000720  50 51 73 74 61 74 75 73  00 50 51 66 69 6e 69 73  |PQstatus.PQfinis|
00000730  68 00 50 51 70 75 74 43  6f 70 79 44 61 74 61 00  |h.PQputCopyData.|
00000740  50 51 72 65 73 75 6c 74  53 74 61 74 75 73 00 50  |PQresultStatus.P|
00000750  51 73 65 74 64 62 4c 6f  67 69 6e 00 50 51 65 72  |QsetdbLogin.PQer|
00000760  72 6f 72 4d 65 73 73 61  67 65 00 50 51 65 6e 64  |rorMessage.PQend|
00000770  63 6f 70 79 00 50 51 70  75 74 43 6f 70 79 45 6e  |copy.PQputCopyEn|
00000780  64 00 6c 69 62 75 76 2e  73 6f 2e 31 00 75 76 5f  |d.libuv.so.1.uv_|
00000790  75 64 70 5f 72 65 63 76  5f 73 74 61 72 74 00 75  |udp_recv_start.u|
000007a0  76 5f 72 75 6e 00 75 76  5f 75 64 70 5f 62 69 6e  |v_run.uv_udp_bin|
000007b0  64 00 75 76 5f 69 70 34  5f 6e 61 6d 65 00 75 76  |d.uv_ip4_name.uv|
000007c0  5f 75 64 70 5f 69 6e 69  74 00 75 76 5f 62 75 66  |_udp_init.uv_buf|
000007d0  5f 69 6e 69 74 00 75 76  5f 69 70 34 5f 61 64 64  |_init.uv_ip4_add|
000007e0  72 00 5f 66 69 6e 69 00  75 76 5f 64 65 66 61 75  |r._fini.uv_defau|
000007f0  6c 74 5f 6c 6f 6f 70 00  6c 69 62 72 74 2e 73 6f  |lt_loop.librt.so|
00000800  2e 31 00 6c 69 62 70 74  68 72 65 61 64 2e 73 6f  |.1.libpthread.so|
00000810  2e 30 00 6c 69 62 6e 73  6c 2e 73 6f 2e 31 00 6c  |.0.libnsl.so.1.l|
00000820  69 62 64 6c 2e 73 6f 2e  32 00 6c 69 62 63 2e 73  |ibdl.so.2.libc.s|
00000830  6f 2e 36 00 65 78 69 74  00 68 74 6f 6e 6c 00 70  |o.6.exit.htonl.p|
00000840  75 74 73 00 5f 5f 73 74  61 63 6b 5f 63 68 6b 5f  |uts.__stack_chk_|
00000850  66 61 69 6c 00 6d 65 6d  73 65 74 00 6d 61 6c 6c  |fail.memset.mall|
00000860  6f 63 00 73 74 64 65 72  72 00 66 77 72 69 74 65  |oc.stderr.fwrite|
00000870  00 66 70 72 69 6e 74 66  00 73 6c 65 65 70 00 5f  |.fprintf.sleep._|
00000880  5f 63 78 61 5f 66 69 6e  61 6c 69 7a 65 00 5f 5f  |_cxa_finalize.__|
00000890  6c 69 62 63 5f 73 74 61  72 74 5f 6d 61 69 6e 00  |libc_start_main.|
000008a0  6e 74 6f 68 6c 00 6e 74  6f 68 73 00 66 72 65 65  |ntohl.ntohs.free|
000008b0  00 5f 65 64 61 74 61 00  5f 5f 62 73 73 5f 73 74  |._edata.__bss_st|
000008c0  61 72 74 00 5f 65 6e 64  00 47 4c 49 42 43 5f 32  |art._end.GLIBC_2|
000008d0  2e 34 00 47 4c 49 42 43  5f 32 2e 32 2e 35 00 00  |.4.GLIBC_2.2.5..|
000008e0  00 00 00 00 02 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 02 00  |................|
000008f0  00 00 00 00 02 00 02 00  02 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
00000900  00 00 03 00 02 00 00 00  02 00 00 00 02 00 00 00  |................|
00000910  02 00 02 00 02 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 02 00 00 00  |................|
00000920  02 00 00 00 00 00 02 00  01 00 01 00 01 00 02 00  |................|
00000930  01 00 01 00 00 00 00 00  01 00 02 00 62 01 00 00  |............b...|
00000940  10 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  14 69 69 0d 00 00 03 00  |.........ii.....|
00000950  01 02 00 00 10 00 00 00  75 1a 69 09 00 00 02 00  |........u.i.....|
00000960  0b 02 00 00 00 00 00 00  80 2d 20 00 00 00 00 00  |.........- .....|
00000970  08 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  30 10 00 00 00 00 00 00  |........0.......|
00000980  88 2d 20 00 00 00 00 00  08 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |.- .............|
00000990  f0 0f 00 00 00 00 00 00  d8 2f 20 00 00 00 00 00  |........./ .....|
000009a0  08 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  28 0d 00 00 00 00 00 00  |........(.......|
000009b0  28 31 20 00 00 00 00 00  08 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |(1 .............|
000009c0  28 31 20 00 00 00 00 00  d0 2f 20 00 00 00 00 00  |(1 ....../ .....|
000009d0  06 00 00 00 07 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
000009e0  e0 2f 20 00 00 00 00 00  06 00 00 00 1d 00 00 00  |./ .............|
000009f0  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  e8 2f 20 00 00 00 00 00  |........./ .....|
00000a00  06 00 00 00 20 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |.... ...........|
00000a10  f0 2f 20 00 00 00 00 00  06 00 00 00 21 00 00 00  |./ .........!...|
00000a20  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  f8 2f 20 00 00 00 00 00  |........./ .....|
00000a30  06 00 00 00 22 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |...."...........|
00000a40  20 32 20 00 00 00 00 00  05 00 00 00 27 00 00 00  | 2 .........'...|
00000a50  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  18 30 20 00 00 00 00 00  |.........0 .....|
00000a60  07 00 00 00 01 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
00000a70  20 30 20 00 00 00 00 00  07 00 00 00 02 00 00 00  | 0 .............|
00000a80  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  28 30 20 00 00 00 00 00  |........(0 .....|
00000a90  07 00 00 00 03 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
00000aa0  30 30 20 00 00 00 00 00  07 00 00 00 04 00 00 00  |00 .............|
00000ab0  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  38 30 20 00 00 00 00 00  |........80 .....|
00000ac0  07 00 00 00 05 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
00000ad0  40 30 20 00 00 00 00 00  07 00 00 00 06 00 00 00  |@0 .............|
00000ae0  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  48 30 20 00 00 00 00 00  |........H0 .....|
00000af0  07 00 00 00 08 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
00000b00  50 30 20 00 00 00 00 00  07 00 00 00 09 00 00 00  |P0 .............|
00000b10  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  58 30 20 00 00 00 00 00  |........X0 .....|
00000b20  07 00 00 00 0a 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
00000b30  60 30 20 00 00 00 00 00  07 00 00 00 0b 00 00 00  |`0 .............|
00000b40  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  68 30 20 00 00 00 00 00  |........h0 .....|
00000b50  07 00 00 00 0c 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
00000b60  70 30 20 00 00 00 00 00  07 00 00 00 0d 00 00 00  |p0 .............|
00000b70  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  78 30 20 00 00 00 00 00  |........x0 .....|
00000b80  07 00 00 00 0e 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
00000b90  80 30 20 00 00 00 00 00  07 00 00 00 0f 00 00 00  |.0 .............|
00000ba0  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  88 30 20 00 00 00 00 00  |.........0 .....|
00000bb0  07 00 00 00 10 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
00000bc0  90 30 20 00 00 00 00 00  07 00 00 00 11 00 00 00  |.0 .............|
00000bd0  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  98 30 20 00 00 00 00 00  |.........0 .....|
00000be0  07 00 00 00 12 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
00000bf0  a0 30 20 00 00 00 00 00  07 00 00 00 13 00 00 00  |.0 .............|
00000c00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  a8 30 20 00 00 00 00 00  |.........0 .....|
00000c10  07 00 00 00 14 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
00000c20  b0 30 20 00 00 00 00 00  07 00 00 00 15 00 00 00  |.0 .............|
00000c30  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  b8 30 20 00 00 00 00 00  |.........0 .....|
00000c40  07 00 00 00 16 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
00000c50  c0 30 20 00 00 00 00 00  07 00 00 00 17 00 00 00  |.0 .............|
00000c60  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  c8 30 20 00 00 00 00 00  |.........0 .....|
00000c70  07 00 00 00 18 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
00000c80  d0 30 20 00 00 00 00 00  07 00 00 00 19 00 00 00  |.0 .............|
00000c90  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  d8 30 20 00 00 00 00 00  |.........0 .....|
00000ca0  07 00 00 00 1a 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
00000cb0  e0 30 20 00 00 00 00 00  07 00 00 00 1b 00 00 00  |.0 .............|
00000cc0  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  e8 30 20 00 00 00 00 00  |.........0 .....|
00000cd0  07 00 00 00 1c 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
00000ce0  f0 30 20 00 00 00 00 00  07 00 00 00 1e 00 00 00  |.0 .............|
00000cf0  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  f8 30 20 00 00 00 00 00  |.........0 .....|
00000d00  07 00 00 00 1f 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
00000d10  00 31 20 00 00 00 00 00  07 00 00 00 23 00 00 00  |.1 .........#...|
00000d20  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  48 83 ec 08 48 8b 05 bd  |........H...H...|
00000d30  22 20 00 48 85 c0 74 02  ff d0 48 83 c4 08 c3 00  |" .H..t...H.....|
00000d40  ff 35 c2 22 20 00 ff 25  c4 22 20 00 0f 1f 40 00  |.5." ..%." ...@.|
00000d50  ff 25 c2 22 20 00 68 00  00 00 00 e9 e0 ff ff ff  |.%." .h.........|
00000d60  ff 25 ba 22 20 00 68 01  00 00 00 e9 d0 ff ff ff  |.%." .h.........|
00000d70  ff 25 b2 22 20 00 68 02  00 00 00 e9 c0 ff ff ff  |.%." .h.........|
00000d80  ff 25 aa 22 20 00 68 03  00 00 00 e9 b0 ff ff ff  |.%." .h.........|
00000d90  ff 25 a2 22 20 00 68 04  00 00 00 e9 a0 ff ff ff  |.%." .h.........|
00000da0  ff 25 9a 22 20 00 68 05  00 00 00 e9 90 ff ff ff  |.%." .h.........|
00000db0  ff 25 92 22 20 00 68 06  00 00 00 e9 80 ff ff ff  |.%." .h.........|
00000dc0  ff 25 8a 22 20 00 68 07  00 00 00 e9 70 ff ff ff  |.%." .h.....p...|
00000dd0  ff 25 82 22 20 00 68 08  00 00 00 e9 60 ff ff ff  |.%." .h.....`...|
00000de0  ff 25 7a 22 20 00 68 09  00 00 00 e9 50 ff ff ff  |.%z" .h.....P...|
00000df0  ff 25 72 22 20 00 68 0a                           |.%r" .h.|
00000df8
```

Если собирать на Arch или Debian - стартует и работает.

Арч gcc7, glibc.

```
file collector
collector: ELF 64-bit LSB shared object, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, interpreter /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2, for GNU/Linux 3.2.0, BuildID[sha1]=d174d4d1db763b1b5106a796e85cdd3c0460e975, not stripped
```

Хед https://yadi.sk/d/FC2vp4VM3Q3WDy

Comment: `$ file /usr/local/bin/collector; head -n 2 /usr/local/bin/collector` ?

Comment: @alexanderbarakin, добавил

Comment: Не может загрузчик файл открыть. Сравните вывод всего, что вы привели для Alpine, с Arch.

Comment: на арче сборка под glibc и gcc7. на альпине gcc6 и musl